# Stuck in JSON parsing. JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android, json

I'm trying to fetch name of cities in a new spinner when I click on a value on a State in previous spinner. It was working fine until I implemented it using AsyncTask in android to avoid application to freeze when making two HTTP calls.

Now when I click on spinner value of States(the list of States gets fetched via HTTP call) the 'City' spinner should be populated with the list of corresponding State values in the table. But unfortunately I get this error in logcat:

> org.json.JSONException: Value

I need someone to help me out of this hellish situation.

Following is the code of Enroll.java:

```
package com.example.dell.bleederz;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class enroll extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener,AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText Name, Passwordone, Passwordtwo, Age, Address, Phone, Email;
    Button REGISTER, RESET;
    Spinner States, City, Bloodgroup;



    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    List<String> list,list1;
    InputStream is = null;
    String val = "";



    String line = null;
    String result = null;
    String name;
    String paso;
    String past;
    String age;
    String bgroup;


    String add;
    String state;
    String city;
    String phone;
    String email;
    int code;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enroll);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameU);
        Passwordone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passUone);
        Passwordtwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passUtwo);
        Age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageU);
        Address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressU);
        Phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobU);
        Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mailU);
        RESET = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Resbutton);
        REGISTER = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Regbutton);
        RESET.setOnClickListener(this);
        REGISTER.setOnClickListener(this);
        States = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.stateU);
        City = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cityU);
        Bloodgroup = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bgroupU);
        addItemsOnBloodgroup();

     //  States.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        SelectState();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list); // set list into ArrayAdapter
        States.setAdapter(adp); // Set


        City.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        new CreateDonor().execute();


    }

    private void SelectState() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/bloodsync/spdemo.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Webservice 1", e.toString());
        }
        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Webservice  state 2", e.toString());
        }
        try {

            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject jo = null;

            list = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                list.add(jo.getString("nameofstate"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Webservice 3", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void addItemsOnBloodgroup() {
        Bloodgroup = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bgroupU);
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("A+");
        list.add("A-");
        list.add("B+");
        list.add("B-");
        list.add("O+");
        list.add("O-");
        list.add("AB+");
        list.add("AB-");
        ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Bloodgroup.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        val = States.getSelectedItem().toString();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adp1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1); // set list into ArrayAdapter
        City.setAdapter(adp1);


    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int i = view.getId();
        name = Name.getText().toString();
        paso = Passwordone.getText().toString();
        past = Passwordtwo.getText().toString();
        age = Age.getText().toString();
        bgroup = Bloodgroup.getSelectedItem().toString();
        add = Address.getText().toString();
        state = States.getSelectedItem().toString();
        city = City.getSelectedItem().toString();
        phone = Phone.getText().toString();
        email = Email.getText().toString();

        switch (i) {
            case R.id.Regbutton:
                insert();
                break;

            case R.id.Resbutton:
                Name.setText("");
                Passwordone.setText("");
                Passwordtwo.setText("");
                Age.setText("");
                Bloodgroup.setSelection(0);
                Address.setText("");
                States.setSelection(0);
                City.setSelection(0);
                Phone.setText("");
                Email.setText("");
                break;

        }
    }

    public void insert() {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nameU", name));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passUone", paso));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passUtwo", past));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ageU", age));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bloodgroup",bgroup ));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addressU", add));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nameofstate", state));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cityname", city));



        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobU", phone));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mailU", email));

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/bloodsync/reg.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 11", "connection success ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address"+e,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 12", "connection success ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }

        try {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            code = (json_data.getInt("code"));

            if (code == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Registered Successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Details Please Fill Your Details Carefully ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }

    }


    class CreateDonor extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city",val));

            try
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/bloodsync/cities.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            try
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                        (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
            }

            try {

                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject jo = null;

                list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                    jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                    list1.add(jo.getString("cityname"));

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Webservice 13", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */

    }
}
```

Following is the code of my PHP file cities.php

```
<?php

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$uname = 'root';
$pwd = '';
$db = 'bloodsync';
$sname= $_REQUEST['city'];

$con = mysql_connect($host, $uname, $pwd) or die('Connection Failed');
mysql_select_db($db, $con) or die('Database Selection Failed');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT cityname FROM cities where statename='$sname'", $con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $flag[] = $row;
}

print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Log what is created here: *print(json_encode($flag));*. Either in your PHP or your Java. Or before here *JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);* log to logcat, your result variable.

Comment: Firstly debug your code and find out what response you are getting.

Comment: post your response the problem is your repose is not of proper format

Comment: @Knossos
This is the output if I enter the name of state as 'Punjab' :


 `[{"0":"Mohali","cityname":"Mohali"}]`

Comment: I think the error is in this line `JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);` 
Just try to print value of `result` variable. I think value is not in proper format.

Comment: Problem is in you php page   try to remove print with echo like this echo json_encode($response);

Comment: @Tufan Tried it already still same error.

Comment: hey try to remove echo from  you page..nd if the problem remains tell us logcat..there is no need of echo statement...

Comment: @Tufan Nope, Still the same exception. :(

Comment: r u using in localhost????

Comment: if you have server than put you code in realtime server..i have same issue so i move my code to real server ..although you can check my code http://paste.ofcode.org/WSK9adNKacNka4EK4praj5  it may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind your `Exception` is that you are not getting your `JSON` response properly.

Try to print `JSON` response in `log-cat`.

You have to pass valid response from `PHP` so your android code can get that response and convert that to string properly.

For that you have to pass headers with response so it can convert string response to `JSON`.

Try below code with your `PHP` code.

> Set the content type with `header('Content-type: application/json');` and then echo your data.

```
<?PHP
    $data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Tried adding header but still I get the same error. I already told, My code was working just fine when I was not using AsyncTask

Comment: Tried putting it on my host & now the change in error:
` org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Comment: make sure that you are getting values from your sql query. You are getting null response it means that your PHP file can not generate proper output. Check with your PHP developer..

Comment: @RamneekSingh adding header cannot generate error unless you are doing it wrong way.. try to create dummy array and pass it as json  response. It you get success in that case means you have to check with SQL query.

Comment: The error was partially resolved so I will accept your suggestion :) Thank you So much ! The rest error resided as follows. The string list was fetched from server via JSON to a JSONArray and android studio had a problem in that guess what? the first Item was null & it was not being able to get into a spinner so I decided to go with Autocomplete text view. :)